# Is this an Activity or a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I know I'm gonna take down votes but I just need to clarify this dilemma with my friend.

In Play Store is this view an Activity or a Fragment?

[image]

Comment: A `PreferenceActivity` most likely

Comment: I decompiled the apk and there's no `SettingsFragment` just a `SettingsActivity` which presumably extends `PreferenceActivity`. Are you and your friend like me a while back and just HAVE TO have everything like Google or what? Just use this and get on with life https://github.com/consp1racy/android-support-preference

Comment: @EugenPechanec No no it's not that, it's just we have a login screen in an  activity and after login i think i should use fragments(in same activity) for what comes next and my friend thinks we should call a new activity. What do you think?

Comment: If you e.g. fill out a profile after login, you could make a LoginActivity witrh LoginFragment and ProfileFragment. Then you could have a MainActivity (with naviogation drawer) and there switch fragments which are related to your app's core functionality. Then you could have separate HelpActivity and SettingsActivity...

Answer (score 5):

Fragments do not exist on their own. Hence, "activity or fragment" is an incorrect comparison. It is either "an activity without fragments" or "an activity with fragments".

Whether that activity uses a fragment or not is impossible to tell, with certainty, from a screenshot.

*Probably* that is using Android's `PreferenceScreen` system. That can be used either with a `PreferenceFragment` or directly with a `PreferenceActivity`. Once again, a screenshot alone cannot distinguish between these cases.

Answer (score 3):

That can be both `PreferenceFragment` or `PreferenceActivity`!! you can embed a `PreferenceFragment` inside normal Activity on android 3.+

Answer (score 2):

This is `Preference` activity. Settings screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can judge it by the animation Google Play uses to move from the preview page to this page.

I think it's an Activity ,because you will use an Activity to set Preferences,a PreferenceActivity or an Activity contains PreferenceFragment.